# Basic Understanding of Async Await Programming in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await

I was trying to understand `Async/Await` Programming Model. I wrote a sample program to understand the same.

I have written 3 independent asynchronous methods named `GetFirstValue`, `GetSecondValue`, `GetThirdValue`.
There is a method named `M1` which executes the above mentioned 3 methods asynchronously and returns the concatenated result of above 3 methods.

My main idea is that if method `GetFirstValue` takes 5 seconds, `GetSecondValue` takes 7 seconds and `GetThirdValue` takes 8 seconds. Then, `M1` should return in less that 20 seconds. As the 3 methods are not synchronous.

But as I didn't understand the concept correctly. I am doing something wrong. Here is the Complete program that I was working on.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LearningAsyncProgramming
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

            AsyncMethodsClass asyncMethods = new AsyncMethodsClass();
            Console.WriteLine(asyncMethods.M1().Result);
            watch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds/1000);
        }
    }

    class AsyncMethodsClass
    {
        public async Task<string> M1()
        {
            string retVal = string.Empty;

            int v1 = await GetFirstValue();
            int v2 = await GetSecondValue();
            int v3 = await GetThirdValue();

            return string.Concat( v1,"-",v2,"-",v3);
        }

        private async Task<int> GetFirstValue()
        {
            int a = await GetTimer();
            return a;
        }
        private async Task<int> GetSecondValue()
        {
            int a = await GetTimer();
            return a;
        }
        private async Task<int> GetThirdValue()
        {
            int a = await GetTimer();
            return a;
        }

        private async Task<int> GetTimer()
        {
            int someNumber = new Random().Next(5,9);

            Thread.Sleep(someNumber * 1000);
            return someNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the updated code after implementing the suggestions in the answers. It does exactly what I was expecting.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LearningAsyncProgramming
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

            AsyncMethodsClass asyncMethods = new AsyncMethodsClass();
            Console.WriteLine(asyncMethods.M1().Result);
            watch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds/1000);
        }
    }

    class AsyncMethodsClass
    {
        public async Task<string> M1()
        {
            // Start all the functions, but don't wait just yet
            var t1 = GetFirstValue();
            var t2 = GetSecondValue();
            var t3 = GetThirdValue();

            return string.Concat( await t1,"-",await t2,"-",await t3);
        }

        private async Task<int> GetFirstValue()
        {
            int a = await GetTimer();
            return a;
        }
        private async Task<int> GetSecondValue()
        {
            int a = await GetTimer();
            return a;
        }
        private async Task<int> GetThirdValue()
        {
            int a = await GetTimer();
            return a;
        }

        private async Task<int> GetTimer()
        {
            int someNumber = new Random().Next(5,9);

            await Task.Delay(someNumber * 1000);
            return someNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `Thread.Sleep` in tasks is not a good idea, use `await Task.Delay(...)` instead.

Comment: "I am doing something wrong", can you please elaborate on why you're saying this? What didn't meet your expectations here? Apart from the Thread.Sleep I mentioned above there are certainly things I would personally do different here but that doesn't make them wrong, but knowing what you intended the code to do, and/or what you expected it to do, that it didn't/doesn't, will help us formulate the best/right answers to your question.

Comment: If "something wrong" is that you expected the three calls to run in parallel, in essence M1 should take as long to execute as the longest of the three, then the answer is that you called each, and awaited their return before you called the next. Instead check the answer provided by @Lukas, it may be exactly what you want.

Comment: This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2moh18sh5p4) really helped me to understand correct usage of await and what to expect when making/using async methods.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes, your 3rd Comment is what I want. I want to run all the 3 methods in parallel and return the result once all method are completed their execution.

Comment: What does the keyword `await` mean?? 
Is it used to wait? or not to wait?

Comment: Okay, So I am concluding that my understanding was correct just the use of `Thread.Sleep(someNumber * 1000);` was making me confuse. Thanks for the big help all you guys.

Comment: Well, not quite, if you swap to Task.Delay you will still run them sequentially, it will just free up some threads while you wait. In fact, in your code you don't have any async code at all, it all runs synchronously because it misses something that would actually be asynchronously executed. Just stuffing `async` on a method doesn't make it async, it makes it *possible* to more *easily* write async code. You got warnings from the compiler for some of your code about this already.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I have updated the question with correctly working code. Could you please tell now whether it is `aync` programming or not?If not, Guide me to the right way of doing it.

Comment: Now it is async, `Task.Delay` introduces the asynchronous element it was lacking before. Merely adding `async` to the method declaration does not make it more async than it was before, it just makes it possible to await async stuff, like `Task.Delay`.

Comment: okay. Thanks for the value information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int v1 = await GetFirstValue();
int v2 = await GetSecondValue();
int v3 = await GetThirdValue();
```

Using `await` in this scenario before each call blocks the code from continuing; you'd want to keep a collection of all of the tasks returned from these calls (without the `await`) and then call `Task.WaitAll` on them.

A revised version of this code:

```
var firstTask = GetFirstValue();
var secondTask = GetSecondValue();
var thirdTask = GetThirdValue();

int v1 = await firstTask;
int v2 = await secondTask;
int v3 = await thirdTask;
```

Comment: You should edit in how he should rewrite the code as well.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're running the `Get` method pseudo-asynchronously. Your call `GetFirstValue` and await the function completing before calling `GetSecondValue` and then `GetThirdValue`.

What you want to do is run them in parallel and then wait for them all to complete:

```
// Start all the functions, but don't wait just yet
var t1 = GetFirstValue();
var t2 = GetSecondValue();
var t3 = GetThirdValue();

// Wait for them all to complete in parallel
await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3);

// Get the results from the task
int v1 = t1.Result;
int v2 = t2.Result;
int v3 = t3.Result;
```

Alternatively you can remove the `WhenAll` and await the individual tasks. As they're all now running it's basically the same:

```
// Start all the functions, but don't wait just yet
var t1 = GetFirstValue();
var t2 = GetSecondValue();
var t3 = GetThirdValue();

// All the tasks are running, so get the results from the task
int v1 = await t1;
int v2 = await t2;
int v3 = await t3;
```

Comment: Do we have alternative for `await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3);` 
Like
`int v1 = await t1;
int v2 = await t2;
int v3 = await t3;`

Comment: @SandeepKushwah - yes you can do that. I'll update the answer to show that